# nested push animation on tableview only when quickly clicking cells when page loads

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a couple tableviews that are pushed when a cell is selected, they are filled by coredata and everything thing works fine most of the time but lets say you are on tableview1 and click cell one repeatably the next tableview comes but then it gets this:

```
nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MasterTableViewController: 0x10365120>.
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

I tried putting `[self.tableView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];`
in viewDidLoad (not sure where it should go) but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to start new push animation before previous is finished. You can use

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

to disable user interaction until animation is finished.

You should place it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method.

Comment: man that was easy thanks, that did the trick and then all i had to do was set it to YES when the viewDidAppear again